# calculate an array of tip amounts, but array is coming empty

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie coder and have been trying to run this code to calculate an array of tip amounts, for some reason this code is coming up with an empty array and I'm not sure why.
 
Any help would be appreciated!

```js
var john = {
  Billamounts: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
  tip: [],
  TipCalc: function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.Billamounts.length; i++) {
      var TIPz;
      var bill = this.Billamounts[i];

      switch (true) {
        case (bill < 50):
          return TIPz = this.Billamounts[i] * (20 / 100);

        case ((bill >= 50) && (bill <= 200)):
          return TIPz = this.Billamounts[i] * (15 / 100);

        case (bill > 200):
          return TIPz = this.Billamounts[i] * (10 / 100);

      }
      this.tip[i] = TIPz;
    }
  }
}

john.TipCalc();
console.log(john.tip);
```

Comment: learning how to use your browser's debugger is a valuable skill.  I would encourage you to try to set a breakpoint and trace your code's execution.  Knowing how to do that would be far more valuable than having this question answered, as you would then easily be able to answer it yourself.

Comment: @adiga thanks! Could you explain why taking out the return works?

Comment: Use `if-else` instead of `switch` and remove `return`. The `return` statement ends the function and returns a value and the code below it will not be executed.

Comment: Because of you should learn swirch usage, switch is compare next parameter but you use true, check tge switch usage

Comment: If you have to use a `switch`, you must add `break` just before you're done with each case so that the switch _stops_ and the thread continues.

Comment: Your title has been edited now, but for the next time, please [write a title that summarizes the specific problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The goal of Stack Overflow is to be a useful resource for people with the same problem _beyond_ the person asking. "_Newbie javascript coder_" tells future readers nothing about the question that is being answered.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the return statements from switch cases, 
Once you return inside the switch case, the place where you are updating `this.tip[i] = TIPz;` is never executed and becomes unreachable.

> **[The return statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)** ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller.
>
> When a return statement is used in a function body, the execution of
>   the function is stopped. If specified, a given value is returned to
>   the function caller.

```js
var john = {
  Billamounts: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
  tip: [],
  TipCalc: function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.Billamounts.length; i++) {
      var TIPz;
      var bill = this.Billamounts[i];

      switch (true) {
        case (bill < 50):
          TIPz = this.Billamounts[i] * (20 / 100);
          break;

        case ((bill >= 50) && (bill <= 200)):
          TIPz = this.Billamounts[i] * (15 / 100);
          break;

        case (bill > 200):
          TIPz = this.Billamounts[i] * (10 / 100);
          break;

      }
      this.tip.push(TIPz);
    }
  }
}

john.TipCalc();
console.log(john.tip);
```

Comment: The explanation is there on top.

Answer (score 0):

`return` will exit the function and return param . So, return after your function need finished.

when you want to left `switch case` used `break`.

Usually,  `if else` is handle such as `boolean logic` and `switch` is decide which case is equal the param .

```
    var  john = {

      Billamounts: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
      tip: [],
      TipCalc: function() {

        for (var i = 0; i < this.Billamounts.length; i++) {
        var TIPz;
        var bill = this.Billamounts[i];

            if(bill < 50){
                 TIPz = bill * (20 / 100);

            }else if((bill >= 50) && (bill <= 200)){
                 TIPz = bill * (15 / 100);

            }else if(bill > 200){
                 TIPz = bill * (10 / 100);

            }
        this.tip[i] = TIPz;   

        }
        return
      }
    }
    john.TipCalc();
    console.log(john.tip);
```